# Continue execution on Exception

Tags: powershell, error-handling, continue

Below is the script I want to execute. The issue here is once an exception occurs it stops executing, I used `continue` in the catch block but that did not work. How do I get it working even after an exception occurs it should loop in `foreach`.

I also used a `while($true)` loop but that went into infinite loop. How to go about it?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
try 
{
# Loop through each of the users in the site
foreach($user in $users)
{
    # Create an array that will be used to split the user name from the domain/membership provider
    $a=@()


    $displayname = $user.DisplayName
    $userlogin = $user.UserLogin


    # Separate the user name from the domain/membership provider
    if($userlogin.Contains('\'))
    {
        $a = $userlogin.split("\")
        $username = $a[1]
    }
    elseif($userlogin.Contains(':'))
    {
        $a = $userlogin.split(":")
        $username = $a[1]
    }

    # Create the new username based on the given input
    $newalias = $newprovider + "\" + $username

    if (-not $convert)
    {
        $answer = Read-Host "Your first user will be changed from $userlogin to $newalias. Would you like to continue processing all users? [Y]es, [N]o"

        switch ($answer)
        {
            "Y" {$convert = $true}
            "y" {$convert = $true}
            default {exit}
        }
    }   

    if(($userlogin -like "$oldprovider*") -and $convert)
    {  

        LogWrite ("Migrating User old : " + $user + " New user : " + $newalias + "    ")
        move-spuser -identity $user -newalias $newalias -ignoresid -Confirm:$false
        LogWrite ("Done")
    }   
} 
}
catch  {
    LogWrite ("Caught the exception")
    LogWrite ($Error[0].Exception)
}
```

Comment: Why not change `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` ? Doesn't work for you?

Comment: Is there a specific line that's causing the exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use `try {...} catch {...}` when you want to handle errors. If you want to ignore them, you should set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` (or `"SilentlyContinue"`) as @C.B. suggested, or use `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"` for the particular operation raising the error. If you want to handle errors from a certain instruction, you'd put that instruction in the `try {...} catch {...}` block, not the entire loop, e.g.:

```
foreach($user in $users) {
  ...
  try {
    if(($userlogin -like "$oldprovider*") -and $convert) {  
      LogWrite ("Migrating User old : " + $user + " New user : " + $newalias + "    ")
      move-spuser -identity $user -newalias $newalias -ignoresid -Confirm:$false
      LogWrite ("Done")
    }   
  } catch {
    LogWrite ("Caught the exception")
    LogWrite ($Error[0].Exception)
  }
}
```

Comment: Since i wanted to log  non terminating errors, setting '$ErrorActionPreference' did not help me much. Only time it worked is '$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"' but than the execution halts on catch. I wanted to continue exection even on error. Please see my answer, that solved my issue. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: You need `Stop` as the error action for `try..catch` to work, because it only catches terminating errors. Without a terminating error there'd be nothing to catch in the first place.

Comment: -ErrorAction doesn't work for exceptions. E.g. if you want to ignore failure of Set-ExecutionPolicy, the only way to get no error output is to Catch[System...] { }. Note you need the space, otherwise Catch is parsed to nothing and that causes an error!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have placed the "catch" outside the loop body, so that aborts the loop.  Put the catch inside the loop

Comment: Please some more explanation and code, as these might help for future reference

Comment: In the OP code, the catch block sits outside the loop.  Here is an example:


    foreach($a in $list)
    {
      try { dosomething }
      Write-Output "Yay, I did something!"
    }
    Catch
    {
      Write-output "Uh-oh.  Armageddon."
    }

When the exception is caught, it is caught outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code as below. Used the following piece of code after `move-spuser -identity $user -newalias $newalias -ignoresid -Confirm:$false`

```
if($?)
{
  LogWrite ("Done!")
  LogWrite ("  ")
}
else
{
  LogWrite ($Error[0].ToString())
  LogWrite ("  ")
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$?`. Ever. Instead check `$LastExitCode` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12679208/1630171)).

Comment: Isn't $LastExitCode for executables, not for PowerShell cmdlets, scripts, or functions?

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me is to set the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to stop, and then reset it back to continue in the catch block:

```
$e = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference="stop"

try
{
     #Do Something that throws the exception
}
catch
{
    $ErrorActionPreference=$e

}

$ErrorActionPreference=$e;
```