# Exceptions swallowed when capturing Invoke-Expression output and redirecting stderr

Tags: powershell

I want to capture and log all output (redirecting stderr) from Invoke-Expression calls, but by doing that any exception that would normally be thrown seems to be swallowed.

Assuming c:\temp\test already exists this command will throw an exception:

```
PS U:\> $cmd = "mkdir c:\temp\test"
PS U:\> $output = Invoke-Expression $cmd
New-Item : Item with specified name C:\temp\test already exists.
At line:38 char:24
+         $scriptCmd = {& <<<<  $wrappedCmd -Type Directory @PSBoundParameters }
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\temp\test:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

But, if I redirect stderr, then nothing happens:

```
PS U:\> $cmd = "mkdir c:\temp\test 2>&1"
PS U:\> $output = Invoke-Expression $cmd
PS U:\>
```

This is a simplified example, and I'm using Invoke-Expression in a function for many types of calls, and logging the output. So it is not just a matter of making this call work.

Furthermore not capturing the output will also throw the exception correctly:

```
PS U:\> $cmd = "mkdir c:\temp\test 2>&1"
PS U:\> Invoke-Expression $cmd
New-Item : Item with specified name C:\temp\test already exists.
At line:38 char:24
+         $scriptCmd = {& <<<<  $wrappedCmd -Type Directory @PSBoundParameters }
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\temp\test:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I see that $Error actually contains the exception, but I don't know if I can be sure that it contains only errors related to the Invoke-Expression call.

But the question stands. How can I capture all output (including stderr) from Invoke-Expression, and still get exceptions thrown?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666101/powershell-lastexitcode-0-but-false-redirecting-stderr-to-stdout-gives-nat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Error` is an array that buffers errors. The most recent error is stored in `$error[0]`. You could use this in combination with `$LASTEXITCODE` and `$?`

For your case I think `-ErrorVariable` is more appropriate. It is a common variable. See `get-help about_commonparameters` for more information. The syntax is `-ErrorVariable [+]<variable-name>`. For example, the following command creates the `$e` variable and then stores any errors from `Invoke-Expression` in it:

```
Invoke-Expression $cmd -ErrorVariable e
```

Note that `$e` can contain more than one error.

So, to answer your question about how to capture all output, and still show errors:

```
$output = Invoke-Expression $cmd -ErrorVariable e
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. $e is empty when running this $output = iex "mkdir c:\temp\test 2>&1" -ErrorVariable e

Comment: $? is true after the command has been run, but $LASTEXITCODE at least shows something.

Comment: `$e` is empty because you are redirecting your `STDERR` to `STDOUT`!

Comment: Redirecting STDERR is very much a core part of my question, and your answer stated that using ErrorVariable would allow me to get errors as well as capture all output.

Comment: With `$output = iex "mkdir c:\temp\test -ErrorVariable e`, `STDOUT` is captured in `$output`, `STDERR` is captured in `$e` and at the same time the exception is thrown. I thought that was your initial question. If you also want to redirect the errors to `$output`, then do `$output += $e` after invocation.

Comment: Thank you. That works great. I didn't understand that I could do without stderr redirection.