# Assigning output of git log to powershell variable

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I want to assign output of git log into a variable, output only goes to the screen and the variable is left null.

```
$log = Push-Location $tempRepo;git init -q;git remote add origin ssh://git@git.weblnk.silverlnka.net/gxp/$repo;git fetch origin $branch -q;git log "$prevCommit..origin/$branch" --name-only --pretty=format: --full-history;Pop-Location

$log.GetType()
```

Also what I would like to do is create an array holding all lines excluding lines that appear empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To capture output from *multiple* statements in PowerShell, enclose them in a *script block* (`{ ... }`) and invoke that with `&`** (or with `.` , if you want the code to run directly in the caller's scope, but that makes no difference for calling *external programs* such as `git`):

```
$log = & { Push-Location $tempRepo;git init -q;git remote add origin ssh://git@git.weblnk.silverlnka.net/gxp/$repo;git fetch origin $branch -q;git log "$prevCommit..origin/$branch" --name-only --pretty=format: --full-history;Pop-Location }
```

**If you also need to capture *stderr* output from external programs** such as `git`, append `2>&1 | % ToString` to the call, but note that `git log` normally outputs just to *stdout*, so no extra effort is needed.

Here's a simple example of a `cmd.exe` command that produces both stdout and stderr output, and how to capture *both* in a PowerShell variable.

```
$out = cmd /c 'ver & nosuch' 2>&1 | % ToString
```

Note:

- In the context of `& { ... }`, you're free to apply `2>&1 | % ToString` to either the entire command group (`& { foo.exe; <# ...#> } 2>&1 | % ToString`);  or to individual commands inside (`& { foo.exe 2>&1 | % ToString; <# .. #> }`)
- `2>&1` can have unexpected side effects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376457/45375) for background information.

---

> what I would like to do is create an array holding all lines excluding lines that appear empty.

**If external-program output comprises more than 1 line, PowerShell automatically captures the output in in an *array* of *individual lines***.

To simply remove empty lines from such an array, use:

```
# Assume that $out contains output captured from an external program.
@($out) -ne ''  # returns sub-array of non-empty lines.
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$log = Push-Location $tempRepo;git init -q;git remote add origin ssh://git@git.weblnk.silverlnka.net/gxp/$repo;git fetch origin $branch -q;git log "$prevCommit..origin/$branch" --name-only --pretty=format: --full-history;Pop-Location`

Because your command line is composed of *multiple*, `;`-separated statements, what `$log = ...` captures is just the output from the *first* statement, `Push-Location $tempRepo` - and since `Push-Location` produces *no* output, `$log` ends up effectively `$null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your commands in a transcript like so:

```
Start-Transcript -Path transcript.txt -NoClobber 

Push-Location $tempRepo
git init -q
git remote add origin ssh://git@git.weblnk.silverlnka.net/gxp/$repo
git fetch origin $branch -q
git log "$prevCommit..origin/$branch" --name-only --pretty=format: --full-history
Pop-Location

Stop-Transcript
$log = Get-Content transcript.txt | ? {$_ -match 'regex to filter unwanted lines'}
```