# Test integrity of archive with 7-Zip in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exit-code, return-code, command-execution

I am trying to test integrity of ZIP file

It looks like this command is working but I got many details about the file.
I want to get a result if the test passed or failed in order to move to the next step.

Any idea how to do it?
Something like:

```
$TestZip = 7z t \\bandit\global\QA\AgileTeam\bandit\Builds\8.6.22.607\8.6.22.607.10.zip

if ($TestZip)
{The test passed}
else
{Test failed}
```

The output is:

```
Path = \\bandit\global\QA\AgileTeam\bandit\Builds\8.6.22.607\8.6.22.607.10.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 5738248794
64-bit = +
Characteristics = Zip64

Everything is Ok

Files: 902
Size:       5927324719
Compressed: 5738248794
```

Tried this:

```
$TestZip = 7z t \\bandit\global\QA\AgileTeam\bandit\Builds\8.6.22.607\8.6.22.607.10.zip | set out
$ok = $out -like '*Everything is Ok*'

if ($ok) {write-host "Integrity test for Zip file passed"}
```

Comment: you run `if ($TestZip)` even before running the command. How can that work?

Comment: It was only for an example what I need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors are reported via [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) so just check it. No need to parse the output, you can just [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2) the output to [null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device). The way to check exit status in PowerShell is `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE`

```
7z t $zip_file_path 2>$null 1>$null
if ($?) {
    echo "Success"
} else {
    echo "Failed"
}
```

#### Update:

Use `if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)` instead of `if ($?)` when stderr is redirected in older PowerShell (7.1.x and older) for more reliable result

---

> ## `$?`
>
> Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains True if the last command succeeded and False if it failed.
>
> ## `$LastExitCode`
>
> Contains the exit code of the last native program that was run.
>
> [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#section-1)

Comment: Great advice; unfortunately, `$?` doesn't work robustly in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.1.x when a `2>` redirection is involved, only `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` works reliably there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376457/45375) for details.

Comment: So I need to use $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 instead of S$?
When the script run I can see the information about the file and I want to see only success or failed

Comment: @Bandit if you want to see the output then don't redirect it. In case stderr is redirected then use `if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)`

Comment: I mean when the 7z t is running there information that I can see and I want to hide it

Comment: This is printed when running the command 

7-Zip 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 5662785272 bytes (5401 MiB)

Comment: @Bandit that's what I said in the answer: redirect the streams. `2` is the stderr and `1` is `stdout`. Did you even try to run it? Redirecting them to `$null` will output nothing on the screen

Comment: Just now I saw the 2>$null 1>$null
Should I need to do both of them?

Comment: yes, both of them is required to suppress both output streams

Comment: @Bandit stream is a very important concept in all shells. If you don't know about it please read [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2), [about Output Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2)