# Can these variables be explained? What is a practical application?

Tags: powershell, variables, built-in

I was looking through PSDrives and the variables listed there and discovered a few and I am not 100% sure what they are doing or what their practical application is.

I run: `echo "test"`

It returns `test`

Easy enough.

From here I run: `$^` and it returns the last command I ran `echo`

When I run `$$` it returns the output of the last command I ran `test`

Is that what they are supposed to do or is that just also what is happening here? What is the practical application?

Also.

Running `$?` always returns `True`

and running `!$?` always returns `False`

What exactly would be the purpose of using these in that context?

```
if(!$?){do something}
```

if what is false? I'm confused.

EDIT:
$^ and $$ return the first and last token.
So I understand that, but still don't see a practical application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables you reference are so-called *automatic variables* in PowerShell, i.e. *built in* ones, as documented in the conceptual [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) help topic.

- `$^` and `$$`, rarely used in practice, are only useful in *interactive* use: they, refer to the first and last token, respectively, of the previously submitted command line.

  - As such, you can use these variables to avoid having to re-type these tokens on the next command line.
  - Note that in order to re-execute the token reported in `$^`, you have to prefix it with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
- [`$?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) is an *abstract success indicator* that reflects whether the most recently executed statement reported an error condition (in which case `$?` is `$false`) or not (in which case it is `$true`).

  - With respect to *PowerShell* commands, an error condition is defined as that command either reporting at least one *non-terminating* error or that command aborting with a statement-*terminating* error.
  - With respect to .NET *method calls*, an error condition means that an *exception* occurred, which surfaces as a statement-*terminating* error in PowerShell.
  - With respect to calls to *external programs*, an error condition means that such a program reports a *non-zero exit code*, as reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

    - *Caveat*: In Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) up to 7.1.x, a `2>` redirection can *falsely* indicate `$false`, even if the process exit code is `0`, namely if the external program happens to produce stderr output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376457/45375) for more information.