# PowerShell, recommended way to do "reg import" operations?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, registry

In a script, I have a number of `reg import` operations. These are all successful, but at the end of my script, I have `$Error > C:\Out\Errors.txt` that helps to clean up various errors, but I am always left with 4 or 5 outputs like this in the `$Error` output:

```
reg : The operation completed successfully.
At D:\MySandbox\MySandbox.ps1:1321 char:18
+ ... e-Command { reg import "$env:TEMP\RegistryEditorSettings.reg" *>&1 |  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The operation completed successfully.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I run the `reg import` operations like this (as a result of reading a Stack Overflow that I can't find now that said you have to do it this way to avoid certain problems - but I'm beginning to think that this syntax *is* the problem):

```
Invoke-Command { reg import "$env:TEMP\RegistryEditorSettings.reg" *>&1 | Out-Null }
```

What would be a recommended way to run `reg import` operations from my script in such a way that they don't generate output in my `$Error` (*unless* there was an error with the `reg import`)?

Comment: Up until recent PowerShell version, redirected native commands polluted the `$Error` variable and caused script-terminating error when `$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'` was in effect (see [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376457/7571258)). If you can't avoid redirection, temporarily set `ErrorActionPreference='Continue'` and remove the unwanted `$Error` records after calling `reg` (e. g. by saving the `$Error.Count` before calling `reg` and delete the difference number of records). Do actual error handling by checking `$LASTEXITCODE`.

Comment: What about `reg import "$env:TEMP\RegistryEditorSettings.reg" > nul 2> nul` directly. It should suppress all the errors OR `reg import "$env:TEMP\RegistryEditorSettings.reg" >nul 2>&1`

Comment: I'm trying both of these options, thanks, all appreciated. I've just stopped all redirection and it's going ok as the script is run by a `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` process, and I see no errors in my error output now.